# How to append a list to an existing list of lists?

Tags: python

If I have a list of lists `[[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2]]` how do I add a 3rd list `[3,3,3,3]` to it to make it `[[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3]]`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `.append()` to append the new list to the existing list of lists.

```
L = [[1,1,1,1], [2,2,2,2]]
L.append([3,3,3,3])

# L = [[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3]]
```